# Is there a way to use a graph to depict the status of a subset of records in a table in power Bi?

Tags: graph, powerbi, visualization

I have a dataset which contains one column for task (e.g. task 1, task 2, task3). These task are repeated in the column as they have sub tasks mapped to them in another column. As well as status of each sub task (ready and not ready). I need a graph that can show me overall status of task 1, task2 and task3. If one of the sub task in task1 is not ready, the graph shows that the entire task1 is not ready and if all sub tasks are ready, the graph shows that the task1 is ready.

An example of the table is below

Answer (score 0):

Your example is missing from your question.

From the sound of it you need a calculated column along the lines of:

Top Level task status =

```
Var topLevelTask = [MyTable]'Task'
RETURN IF (CALCULATE(COUNTROWS([MyTable]), 
           FILTER(ALL([MyTable]), [MyTable]'Task' = topLevelTask 
           && [MyTable]'SubTaskStatus' = "Not Ready")
           > 0, 
           "Not Ready", "Ready")
```